# Most Viewed Taxonomy Terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

What I am looking for it's pretty straightforward. A view in which the most viewed taxonomy terms will be displayed in an ascending order.

To my disappointment the internet is full of articles on how to show taxonomy terms that are ordered on how many times are used in the nodes...so this makes it harder to pinpoint the solution.

Is there a module for this? Or any other solution?

Thanks

Edit: My taxonomy terms are displayed with the default views page
 ex. term/123. So maybe this is something that has to do with the times the view/page of view is displayed?

Comment: So what is the view count you are consider of? The view count on term page or the content page which tagged with the taxonomy term?

Comment: The view count of the term. Isn't that clear in my question? Maybe rephrase it?

Comment: Yes, please rephrase it. I am still confused. Is it **term page**? To me, **term** is an object to load in programming. **term page** is the web page of a term. Also, some people may ask for calculating the total view count of all **article pages** which tagged with same term. They are different concepts.

Comment: Ok. I edited it. Hope makes more sense now.

Comment: Consider the [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module as a very powerful tool for this kind of job, of course it will take some development though, otherwise you can always go the custom way.

Comment: See http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-use-views-aggregator-to-create-taxonomy-term-count-block

Comment: @Justme exactly what I say in my second paragraph. I am not looking for a solution to count how many times a term is used in nodes. I am looking into how many times a term page is viewed by visitors.

Comment: Do you already have a counter for this page?

Comment: @Justme a counter? Actually you gave me an idea that this might be achievable through Access Log and views. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Attached a integer field to the page if you do not have it. Makes rules todo the counting, then aggregate this field in a view together with the term page. Keep me updated.

Comment: @Justme Well...that sounds much better. I guess you are talking about creating a field on my terms. I will give it a try and I let you know.

Comment: Did you managed?

Comment: Well...attach a field to a page? What do you mean exactly? I created an integer field in my terms but in Rules there is no reaction when the term page view is viewed.

Comment: @Justme can you elaborate some more please?

Comment: On holiday till okt